# React Native: Where do I put config files and how do I load them only once?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm looking to install this library: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification.

It says to do this:

```
var PushNotification = require('react-native-push-notification');

PushNotification.configure({

    // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
    onRegister: function(token) {
        console.log( 'TOKEN:', token );
    },

    // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
    onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );
    },

    // ANDROID ONLY: GCM Sender ID (optional - not required for local notifications, but is need to receive remote push notifications) 
    senderID: "YOUR GCM SENDER ID",

    // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
    permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
    },

    // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
    // default: true
    popInitialNotification: true,

    /**
      * (optional) default: true
      * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
      * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
      */
    requestPermissions: true,
});
```

My question is, where would I put this configuration? I don't really want to pollute my component by putting it in `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`. I also want to send push notifications from different components, so I'd like to configure it once and then use it globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the documentation, it looks like you put that configuration boilerplate at the top scope (i.e. not in a component at all) and then call the member functions of PushNotification to send notifications.  If I were organizing a project, I would probably put it in its own js file and export the PushNotification object, then import or require it in my components that needed to send push notifications.

Assuming you're using ES6, you would do something like this:

**PushNotification.js**

```js
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

PushNotification.configure({
    // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
    onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );
    },
});

export default PushNotification;
```

**MyComponent.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';
import PushNotification from './PushNotification';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      message: 'MyComponent mounted!'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyComponent', () => MyComponent);
```